# SSH先のテキストの内容をローカルのクリップボードにコピーする方法

Tags: ssh

SSHで繋いだサーバーにあるテキストの内容をクリップボードにコピーする方法を探しています。

現在はテキスト量が少なく画面内に収まるのであれば、`vim`で開いてマウスでの選択からのコピー、
多すぎる場合は`rsync`でダウンロードしてきてローカルで開くという方法をとっているのですが

もっと簡単にサーバー上にある特定のファイルのテキスト全体をローカルのクリップボードにコピーする方法はないでしょうか？

使用環境はMacでiTermを使っていますが、できるだけローカルの環境依存にしない方法を探しています。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macだと標準で`pbcopy`が使えます。

```
ssh user@example.com 'cat hello.txt' | pbcopy
```

Comment: `pbcopy`というコマンドがあったんですね、ありがとうございます！ ただWindows向けの方法があるかもしれないので、少しの期間質問をオープンにしたいと思います。

Comment: Windowsであれば`clip`コマンドを、Unix Xでは`xclip`を使うのが便利かもしれません。